# Firestore, pagination, loaded data are called again?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I saw the best reply after watching this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&feature=emb_title) and there was a comment like this.

"So there is a read charge even clients app cached the same document data" (currently 24 thumbs up)

And in the comment of another comment, Todd Kerpelman wrote this comment.

"Great question! The answer is that yes, you really will fetch those first 20 documents all the time. Note that this is different than when you have a realtime listener set up and a document changes in a query you're currently listening to - in that case, only the changed doc will be sent up. But if you're making a series of separate get calls that just happen to overlap, the database will send up the entire data set each time."

I am confused now. My question is, when you load the next list with startAfter, do you load the lists that have already been loaded again? Will you be paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when you load the next list with startAfter, do you load the lists that have already been loaded again?

No, for pagination, each query is completely different than the last.  It does not re-fetch all the prior documents again, and you will not be charged for those prior documents.  The query uses the document specified in `startAfter()` to determine exactly where the query should start reading results, and you will be charged for only the documents that are returned by the query.

Comment: thanks. One last little question. When the screen is refreshed (in Flutter, for instance, setState() function). Maybe the data for that query already exists in the cache. Will you pay for it by calling it again? (The same query)

Comment: Every time you perform a query where the results come from the server, it will cost document reads.